# Why won't this validate?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="next.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="my_input">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @klox, are you dreaming?

Comment: Why don't you check yourself? Seriously: http://validator.w3c.org

Comment: errm, I did - that's why I ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validator already told you the reasons.

> document type does not allow element "INPUT" here; missing one of "P", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "PRE", "DIV", "ADDRESS" start-tag

Use

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="next.php" method="post">

<p><input type="text" name="my_input"></p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because according to this DTD inputs need to be nested in one of the following tags: `P`, `H1`, `H2`, `H3`, `H4`, `H5`, `H6`, `PRE`, `DIV`, `ADDRESS`:

```
<p>
    <input type="text" name="my_input">
</p>
```